# Regex match hashtag with exceptions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the current expression:

```
/(?<![http://|https://|#])#([\d\w]+[^\d\s<]+[^\s<>]+)/g
```

However it's not compatible to run on Safari. I'm trying to handle the following cases:

```
#tag => match
#123 => no match
#32bit => match
##tag => no match
http://google.com/#/test => no match
tag##tag => no match
tag#tag => no match
<p>#tag</p> => match only #tag
#tag. => match only #tag
tag## => no match
tag# => no match
this is a match #tag => only #tag
```

I wonder how I can make a character before the match result in a negative match. E.g. `#` and `/`.

Is there any alternative to negative look behind that is compatible with Safari?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good Lord, it's 2022, and Safari still doesn't have look-behind. Yikes.

Comment: `[http://|https://|#]` doesn't make sense, `[]` denotes a *character class*, but you seem to be using it for grouping...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm really mixing things up, I'm no hero in Regex. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a negated character class and a capture group, and make sure that there are not only digits.

Note that `\w` also matches `\d`

```
(?:^|[^\w#/])(#(?!\d+\b)\w+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^` Assert the start of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\w#/]` Match a single non word char other than `#` or `/`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `#` Match literally
  - `(?!\d+\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not only digits to the right followed by a word boundary
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZ94An/1)

```js
let regex = /(?:^|[^\w#/])(#(?!\d+\b)\w+)\b/;
[
  "#tag",
  "#123",
  "#32bit",
  "##tag",
  "http://google.com/#/test",
  "tag##tag",
  "tag#tag",
  "<p>#tag</p>",
  "#tag.",
  "tag##",
  "tag#"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex)
  if (m) {
    console.log(`${s} --> ${m[1]}`)
  }
})
```

Using the matches in a replacement:

```js
let regex = /((?:^|[^\w#/]))(#(?!\d+\b)\w+)\b/;
[
  "#tag",
  "#123",
  "#32bit",
  "##tag",
  "http://google.com/#/test",
  "tag##tag",
  "tag#tag",
  "<p>#tag</p>",
  "#tag.",
  "tag##",
  "tag#",
  "this is a match #tag"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex)
  if (m) {
    console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1<span>$2</span>"))
  }
})
```

Comment: This seems to be correct, however spaces and new lines are included?

Comment: E.g. `this is a match #tag`.

Comment: @MaartenCoppens Should the string no contain spaces?

Comment: I might've not specified that, but it's actual use it to transform hashtags to chips and wrap them in HTML. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @MaartenCoppens I don't know what you mean by that, can you give an example? It matches only #tag, see https://regex101.com/r/xbX1IO/1

Comment: I might not understand regex101's concept, but why is the space and `<` colored in blue?

Comment: @MaartenCoppens If you want to wrap the tag in html, you can use 2 capture groups like this https://regex101.com/r/xxvr3i/1 and then in the replacement use it like this `$1<div>$2</div>` The blue part in the first regex means a match, and the green part a group. If you want to replace AND keep the match and the group you would have to use 2 groups instead.

Comment: E.g. `this is a match #tag` should become `this is a match <span>tag</span>`. This i do via `.replace()` in JS.

Comment: @MaartenCoppens I have added an example with replace and the capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

This satisfies your test cases. Not sure though whether you want this or not.

It does't work on #123 but I forgot it and I'm now lazy to add it as a screenshot.

```
/^(?:[^#]*[^#\w])?(#[\w]*[a-zA-Z][\w]*).*$/g
```

If you only want to allow <tags> before the "#", you can insted use @kendle's solution for the first non-capture group (before the actual group starting with #).

```
(?:<\w*>)?
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like it's matching `</p>`.

Comment: Yeah it does, but it only puts the #tag in the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following pattern the second matching group contains what you want.

```
^(<\w*>)?(#\w+[a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: The actual group capturing the tag content should be more like  this: (#[\w]*[a-zA-Z][\w]*). I would also suggest a non-capturing group for the first one (?:stuffthatwedon'tcareabout)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this, without a capture group, with this regex:

```
/(?<![#\w])#{1}(?!\d+\b)\w+/g
```

```js
const regex = /(?<![#\w])#{1}(?!\d+\b)\w+/g;

const stringToTest = [
    "#tag",
    "#123",
    "#32bit",
    "##tag",
    "http://google.com/#/test",
    "tag##tag",
    "tag#tag",
    "<p>#tag</p>",
    "#tag.",
    "tag##",
    "tag#",
    "this is a match #tag",
];

stringToTest.forEach(str => {
    const match = str.match(regex);
    if (match) {
        console.log(`${str} -> ${match[0]}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${str} -> ${match}`);
    }
});
```

Good luck !